HTTPS access comes and goes
I have just done a clean install of Ubuntu 24.04 server and installed iRedMail with the nginx web interface as a mail server.  I have set a static IP and it works fine for about 2 minutes. Then the web interface reports unable to connect.  Leave it overnight and it's working again.  After about 2 minutes activity it's unable to connect again.
nmap from another machine shows:
Not shown: 992 closed tcp ports (conn-refused)<br>
PORT     STATE    SERVICE<br>
21/tcp   filtered ftp<br>
22/tcp   open     ssh<br>
23/tcp   filtered telnet<br>
53/tcp   filtered domain<br>
389/tcp  filtered ldap<br>
443/tcp  filtered https<br>
465/tcp  filtered smtps<br>
1900/tcp open     upnp<br>

and nmap -v -A <my IP> reports that the host is down.
When the webpage opens as it should nmap also reports:
/tcp   open     smtp<br>
80/tcp   open     http<br>
443/tcp  open     https<br>
587/tcp  open     submission<br>
993/tcp  open     imaps<br>

SSH is working all the time.  I have tried disabling UFW or enabling it with these ports open.
From within the server ss list all ports as Listening.  I have been combed through the log files (mail and syslog), but I can't see anything to indicate dropping the ports.
Can anyone suggest where to look for this erratic behavior?
